# PHP: Adding new lines to PHPMailer plain text email

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

I am using PHPMailer to send from my PHP script to an SMTP server.

To add new lines using php's mail function, I simply add

```
"\r\n",
```

however this does not work with PHPMailer.

I have tried

```
'\r\n'
\r
\n
chr(20)
```

How can I add new lines?

The code is

```
$message =  $contents .
                "\r\n" .
                "\r\n" .
                'Regards';
$mail->AltBody = $message;
```

Where $contents it just a sentence.

Comment: They need to be inside double quotes. `"\r\n"`

Comment: that will depend on what the rest of your code looks like and which method is used to send it as.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson OP states: *"I simply add

"\r\n", 

however this does not work with PHPMailer."*

Comment: @MagnusEriksson why?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Ah, I just looked at the second block.

Comment: if you're trying to send as HTML, then those won't work. You need to use `<br>` or `<p>`. The question is unclear. I'll just leave that in your hands and leave the question. This I fear will take too long.

Comment: @aidinMC If you want PHP to interpret escape sequences for special characters, they must be inside double quotes. Read under "Double quoted": http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- This is for the plan text element of the email.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson this mean `'\n'` not working in php?

Comment: Show us your actual code and how you're adding the new line strings

Comment: @aidinMC -  That will literally print the string `\n`. Check the link i posted and let's stick to the OP's issue for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `<br>` tag. As all body is html. So you can make new line by using `<br>` tag.

I have used like this:

`$mail->Body    = 'text1 <br> text2';`

Comment: This will work 100% if HTML is enabled.

$mail->isHTML(false);